# About Spark GraphX, how can i using other datatype at vertices

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, arangodb, spark-graphx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0CVM.png)

as your see, "3L,5L,7L,2L" is a Long Data Type.

how can i using other scala datatype. such as String.

Comment: the image link is https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0CVM.png

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I still don't know if that's possible. I can share a little workaround though. In my case I assigned ID to all vertices. Hope it will help

```
val VertexRDD: RDD[(VertexId, Array[String])] = vfile.map(line => line.split(",")).zipWithIndex().map(_.swap)
```